# How to get ranged by index with LINQ allow to take previous or next items?

Tags: c#, linq

For example I want to take next 3 items I do this

```
private IEnumerable<T> IndexRange<T>(IList<T> source, int start, int end)
{
     return source.Skip(start).Take(end);
}
```

But I need to be able to take also previous 3 items if I need it.
How that would be possible?
For example:
IndexRange(source, 15, 12);

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov do you have a suggestion?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code is wrong.  It should be:

```
return source.Skip(start).Take(end - start + 1);
```

To do what you're asking it could be:

```
return source.Skip(Math.Min(start, end)).Take(Math.Abs(end - start) + 1);
```

Note that my code assumes that both `start` and `end` are inclusive.